# Linux sorting "ls -al" output by date

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I want to sort the output of the "ls -al" command according to date. I am able to easily do that for one column with command:

```
$ ls -al | sort -k6 -M -r
```

But how to do it for both collumn 6 and 7 simultaneously? The command:

```
$ ls -al | sort -k6 -M -r | sort -k7 -r
```

prints out results I do not understand.

The final goal would be to see all the files from the most recently modified (or v.v.).

Here is the attached example for the data to be sorted and the command used:
[image]

Comment: Can you not just use `ls -lat`?

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs -- in short, `ls` is not meant for programmatic consumption, cannot be reliably used from scripts (particularly when trying to support more than a single platform, implementation and locale), and otherwise should not be (ab)used in this way.

Comment: @arco444 - thanks, did not know about the "t" flag. However, the sort command knowledge is usefull in a more general context, so the question is still valuable.
CharlesDuffy - noted, thanks :)

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius: For example, you might have `ls` output stored in a file, and it could be useful to sort that file by timestamp without re-invoking `ls`. But Charles Duffy is right: `ls` output isn't meant to be processed automatically. If you have GNU Coreutils, `stat --format=...` gives you better control over what's displayed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With sort, if you specify `-k6`, the key starts at field 6 and extends to the end of the line.  To truncate it and only use field 6, you should specify `-k6,6`.  To sort on multiple keys, just specify `-k` multiple times.  Also, you need to apply the M modifier only to the month, and the n modifier to the day. So:

```
 ls -al | sort -k 6,6M -k 7,7n -r
```

Do note Charles' comment about abusing `ls` though.  Its output cannot be reliably parsed.   A good demonstration of this is that the image you've posted shows the month/date in columns 4 and 5, so it's not clear why you want to sort on columns 6 and 7.

Answer (score 12):

The final goal would be to see all the files from the most recently modified

```
ls -t
```

or (for reverse, most recent at bottom):

```
ls -tr
```

The ls man page describes this in more details, and lists other options.

Answer (score -1):

You could try `ls -lsa -it -r`

sample
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ntN3.png)