# Retrieving the last modified file in a directory over FTP using a shell script with curl

Tags: shell, unix, curl, unix-timestamp

I am getting pulling the data from server and placing that in my local.

`curl --verbose --ftp-ssl--user 'username:password' ftp://abc.com:001//this/is/stackoverflow/ > /home/dir1/dir2/dir3`

In ideal scenario i am getting below output after hitting `more dir3` command in unix.

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 owner group 0    Jan 1 2021 00:00 filename1
drwxrwxrwx 1 owner group 0    Jan 1 2022 04:30 filename2
drwxrwxrwx 1 owner group 0    Jan 1 2021 06:30 filename3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 owner group 1122 Jan 1 2022 08:30 filename4
-rwxrwxrwx 1 owner group 2233 Jan 1 2022 10:30 filename5
-rwxrwxrwx 1 owner group 3344 Jan 1 2023 11:30 filename6
```

I want something that the date will be in reverse order. I have tried multiple command below,it didnt work. Was trying to reverse with Month as its 6th col so using `-k6M`

`curl --verbose --ftp-ssl--user 'username:password' ftp://abc.com:001//this/is/stackoverflow/ > /home/dir1/dir2/dir3 | sort -n -t- -k6M | tail -1`

`curl --verbose --ftp-ssl--user 'username:password' ftp://abc.com:001//this/is/stackoverflow/ > /home/dir1/dir2/dir3 | sort -n -t- -k6M`

`curl --verbose --ftp-ssl--user 'username:password' ftp://abc.com:001//this/is/stackoverflow/ > /home/dir1/dir2/dir3 | sort -k6M | tail -1`

some more command i have used. All i want while using curl command , all the files should placed in reverse order in directory itself.

Comment: Files are in the directory, and that is out of your control.  When you do an `ls` or any command that lists the files in the directory, they are sorted somehow.  The default for `ls` is alphabetically.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux sorting "ls -al" output by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412774/linux-sorting-ls-al-output-by-date)